# Passing data between React Native screens (From Screen A to Screen B to Screen C)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parameter-passing, react-navigation

Consider the following scenario. 
Basically we have a `MaterialTopTabNavigator` nested within a `StackNavigator`.

How do I pass my data from the function all the way to the `MaterialTopTabNavigator`. Note that  `MaterialTopTabNavigator` has to first go through `StackNavigator`

**file1.js**

```
const[test,setTest] = useState('testing');
function moveToResults(){
    navigation.navigate('Results', test)
}
```

Here we have a simple function which makes the app navigate to a different screen and it passes the state of `test`. When `moveToResults()` is called it takes us to:

**file2.js** // Note that PostFun is the main page of the StackNavigator.

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function PostFun({navigation}) {
  return (

         <Tab.Navigator 
            initialRouteName="Feed"
            activeColor="#e91e63"
            tabBarOptions={{
                labelStyle: {fontSize:12, color:"#faa19b"},
                tabStyle: {height:65, justifyContent: "flex-end"},
            }}
            style={styles.header}>
                <Tab.Screen name="Activity" component={FindFunActivity} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Event" component={FindFunEvent} />
        </Tab.Navigator>

  );
}
```

File2.js is the beginning of the `MaterialTopTabNavigator, as you can see this navigation has two top tabs (Activity and Event).

One of the tabs might look something like and this is where I need my variable to show up:

**file3.js**

```
const FindFunEvent = (navigation) =>{
return(
<View>
    <Text>{navigation.getParam()}</Text>
</View>
)
```

}

**The question**

How do I get my `test` variable to display in the `FindFunEvent` component?

This is much harder to explain than anything, here a visual if you'd prefer.

[Here is the link to a short video that goes over the issue](https://gfycat.com/repentantathletickentrosaurus)

Comment: ```getParam``` works in v4. since you are using v5 you should use ```this.props.route.params```

Comment: @SDushan Thank you for your help, just to better understand, you would do something like: `this.navigation.route.params`? Am I getting this right?

Comment: it is just ```route.params```. check this - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

Comment: @SDushan Nothing happens, I actually get a route var missing error. The issue is that the variable has to go through two navigations before it gets to the final display place.

Comment: what you mean by 2 navigations?

Comment: @SDushan So in my last screen ( not sure if you got a chance to look at the short video) I have a nested `MaterialTopNavigation` within a `StackNavigation`. The var, from file1.js would first stop at `StackNavigation` which would be file2.js and then move to `MaterialTopNavigation` file3.js final destination. I think I need to find a way to continue the flow of the var in file2.js, Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this working, passing the value as component's prop:

**file1.js**

```js
const[test, setTest] = useState('testing');

function moveToResults(){
    navigation.navigate('Results', { test: test })
}
```

**file2.js**

```js
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function PostFun({ route, navigation }) {
  const { test } = route.params;

  return (
        <Tab.Navigator 
            initialRouteName="Feed"
            activeColor="#e91e63"
            tabBarOptions={{
                labelStyle: {fontSize:12, color:"#faa19b"},
                tabStyle: {height:65, justifyContent: "flex-end"},
            }}
            style={styles.header}
        >
          <Tab.Screen name="Activity">
              { (props) => <FindFunActivity {...props} myProp='test'  /> }
          </Tab.Screen>

          <Tab.Screen name="Event" component={() => <FindFunEvent test={test} />} />
        </Tab.Navigator>

  );
}
```

**file3.js**

```js
const FindFunEvent = ({ test }) => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>{ test }</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Similar example can be viewed here:
https://snack.expo.io/UDHVnSUwK

Comment: I see where you are going with this. Thank your your help. I get this Warning when I try to display that: **Looks like you're passing an inline function for 'component' prop for the screen 'Event' (e.g. component={() => <SomeComponent />}). Passing an inline function will cause the component state to be lost on re-render and cause perf issues since it's re-created every render. You can pass the function as children to 'Screen' instead to achieve the desired behaviour.**

Comment: @IlllIl edited the answer (see line 17 - file2.js). Using this new way (screen as tab children) you can hide the warning and achieve your goal! I updated the snack.expo to get a demo, if you need.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. It looks like the warning is still there even after making the changes as you did in file2.js. I think the issue warning flag resides in the Screen Event where we have the inline function.

Comment: You're welcome! About the warning, i think yes, but using inline function is the common way to pass props to Tab.Screen. This warning just don't make sense to me. Anyway, if you get this working, thanks for requesting!

Comment: If you got time and if you have an idea of what is going on I just ran into another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630313/react-native-await-not-blocking-execution

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to navigate and pass the value you got in Screen A to screen B and screen C. 
You can do something like this

ScreenA

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB',
   {value: 'hi', });
}
```

Screen B

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenC',
    this.props.route.params.value);
}
```

Screen C

```
 this.props.route.params.value
```

Comment: Thanks @James for the help! What if I want to go to Screen C though? and by Screen C I mean that the variable has to go from A -> B -> C. It cannot go from A-> C.

Comment: @IlllIl No problem! I edited my answer accordingly. You will be able to access the value in A and B and C.

Comment: What changes would you make the **file2.js** in order to receive and pass that data to the next screen? **file2.js** is basically the middle point between the other two screens, it will have to receive and pass. Hope I am making sense.

Comment: @IlllIl Oh i see, your file2.js is a  navigation routing file. This seems like a bad architecture since I don't think there is a way to store a data inside your navigation. Your navigation component should be strictly just for navigating components and not storing data. Can I ask why you want to store it inside the navigator?

Comment: I am not sure if you had a chance to click on the link and watch the short GIF, but basically I only care to be able to display the data in the **file3.js** but somehow I think it has to go through **file2.js**. If there is a way to bypass **file2.js** I would be glad to do some, but I am not sure that there is one.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this would be use to a `global.data`. When you use a global variable you can use it anywhere within the app. This is not ideal though, as it is not best practice in programming to use global. I am not entirely sure if what you are trying to is possible, if it is not, you could resort to using global.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was hoping to avoid globals as you suggest they are not "best practice".