# {React Native} Async\Await not working properly with setSate

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

Can someone help me understand what I am not doing correctly?
Consider this simple code

```
 var images = []; 
 const [funImage, setFunImage] = useState([]);


//Some function that does this below
firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunActivities').where("location", "==" , place).get().then((querySnapshot) =>{
        querySnapshot.forEach(async(doc) =>{ 
            const ref = firebase.storage().ref('images/'+ doc.data().image)
            const result = await ref.getDownloadURL();
            images.push(result);                                                                   
           })
           setFunImage(images);
       });
```

I am not understanding why `setFunImage(images);` gets executed before `images.push(result);` finishes to push all the results into the array. I thought await would block the remainder of the code below it
Basically the concept behind what I am trying to do is to have all my results pushed to `images` and THEN call `setFunImage(images);`.

How can I achieve that? Is it even possible?

**EDIT**

I changed my code in hope to find a solution to this and this is where I got to so far:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunActivities').where("location", "==" , place).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
   querySnapshot.forEach(async(doc) => {
     const ref = firebase.storage().ref('images/' + doc.data().image)
     const result = await ref.getDownloadURL();
     images.push(result);
     setFunImage(...funImage,images);
     }) 
});
```

Interestingly enough, when this function executes `funImage` is populated with 1 image, but then when I refresh it gets populated with the rest of my images that I have in my firebase.

Take a look at this [GIF of my running app and the issue with the setState](https://gfycat.com/thinshoddygrouper)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code doesn't work because your forEach is running async code. This means it will finish running after you set your images.
Here's a fix with some explanations in the comments -

```
// No need for images array outside
const [funImage, setFunImage] = useState([]);

...

firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunActivities').where("location", "==" , place).get().then(async (querySnapshot) =>{
    // instead of foreach, using map to aggregate the created promises into one array
    // Promise.all takes an array of promises and resolves after all of them completed running
    // returns an array with the promise results
    const images = await Promise.all(querySnapshot.map(async(doc) =>{ 
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref('images/'+ doc.data().image)
        const result = await ref.getDownloadURL();
        return result;                                         
    }));
    setFunImage(images);
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I will test this out ASAP and I will let you know.

Comment: It does not work unfortunately. I don't get my funImage populated, any other thoughts?

Comment: You should try changing `querySnapshot.map` to `querySnapshot.docs.map` since `querySnapshot` isn't an Array like you might expect: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html